# How can I find a static class initializer by reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, static-initializer

How can I find a static class initializer in C# using reflection? Even `GetMembers()` invoked on the type of a class does not seem to provide that information.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`type.TypeInitializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.typeinitializer.aspx) to find it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10241257)

Comment: @MichaelDunlap - even *without* the link, it does answer "*How can I find a static class initializer?*".

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. One additional question: By experimenting with `TypeInitializer` it seems that as soon as I have at least one static (read only) variable within a class a static initializer seems to be generated automatically. I guess there is no way to distinguish between an explicitely defined initializer within a class and an implicitely defined one by the compier?

Comment: @RegisMay i'm not sure. i didn't see anything on `ConstructorInfo` that would give a clue to that information. Perhaps that would be best asked as a new post.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to call static constructor by using reflection. Is this what you are looking for.

Type myClass = typeof (MyClass); 
myClass.TypeInitializer.Invoke(null,null);

Comment: Thank you, yes. Both answers are correct. The property `TypeInitializer` is what I am looking for.